Vintage of this lower bound on skewness for positive data with given mean and sd?
It turns out there is a lower bound on the skewness $g_1$ of any strictly positive set of data having a given mean μ and standard deviation σ:
$$
g_1 > \sigma/\mu - \mu/\sigma.
$$
Although discussed as a fresh result in some recent literature, it seems to me likely to be quite ancient — for reasons I outlined in this PubPeer post (which also contains an elementary proof).
Coming here to ask this Q, I encountered 2 questions to which this result applied immediately: see my answers here and here.  So this suggests the lower bound is at least less well-known than it should be.  But could it possibly be of recent vintage?

You appear to be at the start of this Terence Tao story, my point being that sometimes even relatively basic results exist only on the periphery of the literature: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/12/03/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues-a-survey-of-a-basic-identity-in-linear-algebra/

In my experience, statistical theory from the late 40s, 50s and 60s has been heavily forgotten, particularly results concerning cumulants. It's possible that this result would have been known at the time, but I haven't encountered it myself before. However, while this result is a nice little one, I guess there is also the question of how relevant it actually is? Perhaps whenever is was rediscovered, it was never shared broadly? It's very possible that it has never been published before, due to the lack of a clear situation to publish it. Perhaps a textbook or class exercise?

Guillaume, I would argue the result has found a worthwhile application in this PubPeer comment.

What do you mean by vintage? Do you want to know the year that this result first appeared?

Sextus, thanks for requesting this clarification. Yes, ideally I would like to know when the result first appeared in print. But I know 'earliest' is a tall order! I honestly would be happy for any archaeological find that increases the lower bound on the result's age.
